# How to compile php without unneeded functions to a single file?

Tags: php, compilation

I'm trying to create a very small php binary for a specific use. I don't need many of the functions and classes included in commong php. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: What is your specific use case? Unless the case is *really* good, this sounds like a ton of pointless work. Work that you would have to repeat every time a new version comes out.

Comment: Use `./configure --without-gd --without-spl` and so forth, or even use an older version for building a smaller binary.

Comment: I presume this is for an embedded system, like the web interface for a router?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout php source form svn or download source dist on php.net and build it using manual. It is better to do it on *nix systems or compile PHP with cygwin on Win*. You can easy configure php extensions when building it and exclude some of it using configure script. If you need more specific configurations you should know how Autotools works couse php uses it.